# what is the difference between register_pernet_subsys and register_pernet_device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

http://lists.openfabrics.org/pipermail/general/2007-January/032093.html says

> At creation all subsys init functions are called before device init
>   functions, and at destruction all device exit functions are called
>   before subsys exit function.

Perhaps it's the answer. However, it's been 8 years since the post. It may not be correct anymore.

I read the code in linux/net/core/net_namespaces.c, and still not totally understand it.

Can anyone help me out? THX.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'll answer my own question after several months learning.

The key point lies on the understanding of list ([include/list.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h)).
If you are not faimiar to this data structure widely used by linux kernel, you are suggested to write some code with it first.

[Initially](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/net_namespace.c#L28), *pernet_list* and *first_device* both are a pointer to the same list head.

If register_pernet_subsys is called, *pernet_list* and *first_device* will still be the same one points to the list head. Precisely, each of them points to the privious location, if register_pernet_device has not been called.

However, after calling register_pernet_device, *first_device* will point to the new list_head, while *pernet_list* still point to the original list head.